# My collisions in Unity 3d are not working (new)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know i have already posted a post like this, but I need some more help - im using a different character, and the collision isnt working. Heres a screenshot of the player:
[image]

[image]

Heres the screenshot of the enemy or lava:
[image]

And heres the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Death : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "enemy") {
            Debug.Log("works");
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at tons of videos, nothing has worked. Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong? (P.S. im using the third person template on 2021.3.29f1)

Answer (score 0):

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) works with Rigidbody, and OnTriggerEnter works with BoxColliders (infact all colliders).

I see that the scripts Death.cs is attached to PlayerArmature, but there is no RigidBody component. For Box, Mesh, Capsule or any other collider, you can use

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //trigger based collision for non physics objects.
}
```

for Physics based collision you can use with Rigidbody component

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //physics based collision
}
```